# Check and see if all elements of a list match a parameter

Tags: haskell

I want to make a function that checks to see if each row of the board for the  [Bert Bos puzzle](http://mathcs.pugetsound.edu/~tmullen/pages/bertspel/) is red one row at a time, but conceptually I'm having a hard time with this. Initially I make the board with all blue squares, but once the squares have been flipped with a flip function, the allRed function should be able to tell if the row is all red or not.  Each row is represented by a list of colors, either Blue or Red

I know I should be using the `all` function, but I'm having some problems actually writing it out for my situation

Here is what I have so far:

```
generateboard :: Int -> [[Color]]
generateboard n = replicate n (replicate n Blue)


allRed :: [[Color]] -> Bool
let board = generateboard
allRed board = []
allRed board = all ([x:_ | x <- board, x == Red]) 
  allRed board
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many mistakes and misunderstandings here. I recommend reading any of the [introductory Haskell materials](https://wiki.haskell.org/Learning_Haskell) to strengthen your basic understanding of the language. I will answer the question directly nonetheless.

`generateboard` looks great.

You are right to think `all :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool` will help us define `allRed`. If the type is confusing you can instead think of it as `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`. [The documentation says](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all):

> Determines whether all elements of the [list] satisfy the predicate.

To use `all` we need a predicate (a function) with type `a -> Bool` and a list of type `[a]`. We know what the predicate needs to be:

```
\x -> x == Red
```

Another way to write this is:

```
(==) Red
```

The predicate has type `Color -> Bool` and so our list must then have type `[Color]`. However, we have a list of type `[[Color]]`. There are two ways I can see to go about this.

The simpler idea is to observe that the board structure is irrelevant if all we care about is the cells. Therefore, we can flatten the structure with `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]`. Then our solution is thus:

```
allRed xs = all ((==) Red) (concat xs)
```

Which is also written:

```
allRed = all ((==) Red) . concat
```

Another solution is to observe that if all rows are red then the whole board must be red. This solution is:

```
allRed xs = all (all ((==) Red)) xs
```

Which is also written:

```
allRed = all (all ((==) Red))
```

Comment: When you write `((==) Red)`, the inner parentheses are now redundant right? (I am asking for my own sake since I am relatively new to Haskell.)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice No they are not redundant. Rather, removing the parentheses uses a special syntax feature called operator sections. `(==) Red` is equivalent to `(Red ==)` (a left-section). `(== Red)` is equivalent to `\x -> x == Red` or `flip (==) Red`. To go from `(==) Red` to `(== Red)` directly we have to realise that `==` is symmetric. If you do that, then `((==) Red)` becomes `((== Red))` and then clearly a set of parentheses is redundant.

Comment: So `((==) Red)` is partial function application which applies the function `(==)` to the argument `Red`. In this particular case since `(==)` is symmetric, we get the same behavior if you remove the inner parentheses and use a section. However, in general, the parentheses might be necessary for a non-symmetric operator. Is that correct?

Comment: That is true but it is a strange way to say the parentheses are redundant. Usually we are talking about precedence when we say that. For example, `1 + (2 * 3)` has redundant parentheses because `*` precedes `+`. Your case is different because by removing the parentheses we are actually using a completely different notation.

Comment: I see. In the example `1+(2*3)`, the parse tree is the same with or without the parentheses. However, `((==) Red)` parses differently when the inner parentheses are removed. Thanks for helping me to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `all` function:

```
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all p xs = ...
```

takes a function `p` representing a property and a list `xs` and tests if `p x` is true (i.e., if `x` has property `p`) for every element `x` of `xs`.  (For example, `all even [2,4,7]` checks if all elements of the given list are even, and it returns `False` because `even 7` equals `False`.)  So, to use `all`, you need *two arguments* -- a list of items to check, and a function that checks one item.

Second, when faced with the problem of processing a data structure in Haskell (in this case `[[Color]]`), an excellent rule of thumb is to the deconstruct the structure from the outside in, using one function for each level of structure.  You have an (outer) list of (inner) lists of colors, so start with the outer list, the list of rows.

How would you write a function that checks if *all* the rows in the outer list satisfy the property that they "contain only red colors"?  Or, to put it more simply, how would you write this function using `all` if you already had a helper function `redRow` that expressed the property of a row having only red colors?

```
redRow :: [Color] -> Bool
redRow row = ...
```

If you can write `allRed board` using `all`, `board`, and `redRow`, you'll have reduced the problem to writing the definition of `redRow`, which operates on a simpler data structure, an (inner) list of colors.

To write `redRow`, you should likewise be able to use `all` again with a function expressing the property of a color being red:

```
isRed :: Color -> Bool
isRed col = ...
```

(or using an equivalent lambda or "section" directly).

In this case, another approach is possible, too -- you could use `concat` to "flatten" the outer and inner list together and then tackle the easier problem of checking if all colors in a big long list are red.